# How to create a checkbox in the Properties>Render tab?

Tags: scripting, interface

sorry for the noob question, but i can't create a simple checkbox inside the render tab...
Here is my code...

```
import bpy
from bpy import context
from math import degrees, floor
#from bpy.types import *
from bpy_extras.io_utils import ExportHelper
from bpy.props import BoolProperty
from bpy.types import (Panel,
                       Operator,
                       AddonPreferences,
                       PropertyGroup,
                       )
class MySettings(PropertyGroup):

my_bool = BoolProperty(
    name = "render scene",
    description = "render a reference copy of the scene",
    default = False    
    )       

class BlenderCam_exportFile(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "myops.blendercam_export_file"
    bl_label = "Export File"

    def execute(self, context):
        #------------------------------------
        #    my code is here....
        #------------------------------------
        return {'FINISHED'}

class BlenderCamPanel(bpy.types.Panel):
    """Creates a Panel in the Render context of the properties editor"""
    bl_label = "BlenderCam"
    bl_idname = "blendercam_panel"
    bl_space_type = 'PROPERTIES'
    bl_region_type = 'WINDOW'   
    bl_context = "render"    

    @classmethod 
    def poll(self,context):
        return True

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        scene = context.scene
        rd = scene.render
        #label
        layout.label(text="Label")
        #chechbox      
        layout.prop(rd, "my_bool", text="Bool Property")
        #button
        row = layout.row()
        row.operator("myops.blendercam_export_file")

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(BlenderCam_exportFile)
    bpy.utils.register_class(BlenderCamPanel)
    bpy.utils.register_class(MySettings)

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(BlenderCam_exportFile)
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(BlenderCamPanel)
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(MySettings)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

The code runs fine and doesn't return any error, but while the label and the button are present, the checkbox doesn't show up... Any clue?

Comment: Indent your code in the class declaration for MySettings, add a pointer in the register section `bpy.types.Scene.my_props = bpy.props.PointerProperty(type=MySettings)` as well as removing the pointer in the unregister section `del bpy.types.Scene.my_props` in you panel change to `layout.prop(scene.my_props, "my_bool", text="Bool Property")` and it should function but I'll let someone else answer for cleaner coding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am no python expert however the reason why the bool wasn't showing it was because it was assigned to some property that didn't exists.
If you launch blender from the terminal is easier to spot those problems.

```
code... 
    rd = scene.render
code... 

output
    rna_uiItemR: property not found: RenderSettings.my_bool
    /Text:58
```

--

Looking the documentation,

> `layout` defines the structure of the panel in the UI and `prop`
>   exposes the RNA item and places it into the layout.

The `prop function` takes `data` and `property` as arguments which in your case was `data=rd property=“my_bool”`. now the problem was arising because the variable `rd` was assigned to `scene.render` thus `layout.propr(data=scene.render,  property=“my_bool”)`

looking the error `property not found: RenderSettings.my_bool` we can understand that the `scene.render` was in fact the wrong call as it was calling the `RenderSettings` where there was no property "my_bool".

hence creating the `bpy.types.Scene.my_tool` and assign it to `PointerProperty(type=MySettings)` (that points to the BoolProperty where my_bool exists) solved the problem when calling `layout.propr(data=scene.my_tool,  property=“my_bool”)` because in fact now we know that `my_tool` has an attribute `my_bool`

--

I am not really familiar with the blender addon workflow so I look  [How can I add a checkbox in the tools UI?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/35007/how-can-i-add-a-checkbox-in-the-tools-ui) and made the changes to your code accordingly 
.

```
import bpy
from bpy import context
from math import degrees, floor
#from bpy.types import *
from bpy_extras.io_utils import ExportHelper
from bpy.props import (StringProperty,
                       BoolProperty,
                       IntProperty,
                       FloatProperty,
                       FloatVectorProperty,
                       EnumProperty,
                       PointerProperty,
                       )
from bpy.types import (Panel,
                       Operator,
                       AddonPreferences,
                       PropertyGroup,
                       )

class MySettings(PropertyGroup):

    my_bool = BoolProperty(
        name = "render scene",
        description = "render a reference copy of the scene",
        default = False    
    )       

class BlenderCam_exportFile(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "myops.blendercam_export_file"
    bl_label = "Export File"

    def execute(self, context):
        #------------------------------------
        #    my code is here....
        #------------------------------------
        return {'FINISHED'}

class BlenderCamPanel(bpy.types.Panel):
    """Creates a Panel in the Render context of the properties editor"""
    bl_label = "BlenderCam"
    bl_idname = "blendercam_panel"
    bl_space_type = 'PROPERTIES'
    bl_region_type = 'WINDOW'   
    bl_context = "render"    

    @classmethod 
    def poll(self,context):
        return True

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        scene = context.scene

        # --> new line here <--
        rd = scene.my_tool

        #label
        layout.label(text="Label")
        #chechbox      
        layout.prop(rd, "my_bool", text="Bool Property")
        #button
        row = layout.row()
        row.operator("myops.blendercam_export_file")

def register():
    # --> new line here <--
    bpy.utils.register_module(__name__)
    bpy.types.Scene.my_tool = PointerProperty(type=MySettings)


    #bpy.utils.register_class(BlenderCam_exportFile)
    #bpy.utils.register_class(BlenderCamPanel)
    #bpy.utils.register_class(MySettings)

def unregister():
    # --> new line here <--
    bpy.utils.unregister_module(__name__)
    del bpy.types.Scene.my_tool


    #bpy.utils.unregister_class(BlenderCam_exportFile)
    #bpy.utils.unregister_class(BlenderCamPanel)
    #bpy.utils.unregister_class(MySettings)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

[image]

Comment: Nice! It works now!
However, i don't get why it works... what is the "rd" parameter? I mean, the scene.my_tool property, what is it and what is it used for?

Comment: I update the answer with some explanation. hope it makes sense and hope I understood correctly ahah :)